# How to set emulator sensor values programmatically?

Tags: android-emulator, sensors

I'm looking for a way to set the x, y, and z values for the accelerometer sensor on an android emulator for tests using espresso. My test requires that the device be positioned in a specific way and I am aware that the android emulator has extended controls to modify the rotation and movement of the virtual sensors. However, I am looking for a way to do this automatically without needing to use the extended controls or physically moving an actual device.

I have successfully modified the virtual sensors through the emulator console when connecting to the emulator via telnet; however, I haven't found a way to achieve this programmatically. To do this via telnet, I first needed to enter an authentication token, then, I used the following console command `sensor set acceleration x:y:z`.

I have previously used `adb shell dumpsys battery set level <percent>` to modify the battery level of the device and I was wondering if there was a similar command to modify the x, y, and z components of the accelerometer.

Is there a way to achieve my goal programmatically, or will I need to aim for manually manipulating either the emulated or physical device during tests?

Comment: Have you managed to solve the problem of setting the value of the accelerometer sensor programmatically?